# Questions regarding circumvention of company security policy

Tags: discussion

Where is the line drawn (is there one) when someone asks a question [like this](https://askubuntu.com/q/925598/606758), hoping to elicit a response that would enable him/her to circumvent security policies put in place by the businesses that employ him/her?

While I could answer this person's question, I don't really feel comfortable doing so as it could enable the individual to compromise the security of the networks and systems in operation at his/her place of business.

Are their any guidelines surrounding issues like this? Should there be?